# How to influence value for RPATH in a given gcc/configure environment?

Tags: linux, gcc, bazel, rpath, foreign-cc

I'm currently facing the following fuzzy problem: I'm wrapping the `configure`/`make` based build process for a library my project depends on in a Bazel environment using `foreign_cc` and I need to set the value for `RPATH` to a fixed value.

I managed to inject `"-Wl,--rpath,SOME_VALUE"` using the `copts` argument which results in `ASFLAGS` `CFLAGS` and `CXXFLAGS` being set inside the resulting build-script, which *kind of* seems to work, but the binaries created by Bazel contain a strange combination of paths *prefixed* to the one I've set:

```
$ objdump -x bazel-bin/external/path/to/binary | grep PATH
  RPATH                /opt/gcc-12.2.0/lib/../lib64:/long/path/inside/bazel/cache:SOME_VALUE
```

Trying to reproduce this behavior outside Bazel, i.e. fetching/extracting the source, running `.configure` with the exact same environment variables and running `make install` similar to the build script used by Bazel results in exactly the value for `RPATH` I need it to have

```
$ objdump -x dest/usr/local/lib/binary  |grep 'R.*PATH'
  RUNPATH              SOME_VALUE
```

So what's going on? What does the Bazel-Buildscript do differently to get to those concatenated value for `RPATH`?

Well, I guess there are some differences I just don't think about, but I have no clue where to start. Is there a hidden environment variable I can set which says "prefix the intended value for `RPATH` with some values extracted from the toolchain"?

Here is the part of `build_script.sh` which actually builds the binaries, which I ran externally, too, but with different results:

```bash
ARFLAGS="rcsD" \
AR_FLAGS="rcsD" \
ASFLAGS="-U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -fstack-protector -Wall -Wunused-but-set-parameter -Wno-free-nonheap-object -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-canonical-system-headers -Wno-builtin-macro-redefined -D__DATE__="redacted" -D__TIMESTAMP__="redacted" -D__TIME__="redacted" -Wl,--rpath,SOME_VALUE" \
CFLAGS="-U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -fstack-protector -Wall -Wunused-but-set-parameter -Wno-free-nonheap-object -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-canonical-system-headers -Wno-builtin-macro-redefined -D__DATE__="redacted" -D__TIMESTAMP__="redacted" -D__TIME__="redacted" -Wl,--rpath,SOME_VALUE" \
CXXFLAGS="-U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -fstack-protector -Wall -Wunused-but-set-parameter -Wno-free-nonheap-object -fno-omit-frame-pointer -std=c++0x -fno-canonical-system-headers -Wno-builtin-macro-redefined -D__DATE__="redacted" -D__TIMESTAMP__="redacted" -D__TIME__="redacted" -Wl,--rpath,SOME_VALUE" \
LDFLAGS="-fuse-ld=gold -Wl,-no-as-needed -Wl,-z,relro,-z,now -B/usr/bin -pass-exit-codes -lstdc++ -lm -L$EXT_BUILD_DEPS/openssl/lib" \
AR="/usr/bin/ar" \
CC="/usr/bin/gcc" \
CXX="/usr/bin/gcc" \
RANLIB=":" \
CPPFLAGS="-I$EXT_BUILD_DEPS/openssl/include" \
./configure
$EXT_BUILD_ROOT/bazel-out/k8-opt-exec-2B5CBBC6/bin/external/rules_foreign_cc/toolchains/make/bin/make install
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm gonna go ahead and assume you're using the auto-resolved toolchain (specifically on Linux by the looks of it).. the `RPATH` bits you're looking at would come from the [`runtime_library_search_directories`](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/blob/772cddeeafbd43cbc38cdb11f22636c59d240ac9/tools/cpp/unix_cc_toolchain_config.bzl#L548) feature which inserts `-rpath` dynamically linking binaries... so that they work with `bazel run` or `bazel test`.

Generally speaking, for `cc_*` rules the tool configuration is a function of toolchain configuration (your own or auto-resolved and configured). It processes different pieces of information (user passed config) as well build derived (such as where to expect solibs in the resulting tree) to get the complete call. The flags added through `copts` attribute are processed by `user_compile_flags` feature ([like this](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/blob/772cddeeafbd43cbc38cdb11f22636c59d240ac9/tools/cpp/unix_cc_toolchain_config.bzl#L374)). The "other" `-rpath` arguments are as mentioned added by `runtime_library_search_directories` feature based on `runtime_library_search_directories` variable which will be populated by bazel as it adds solibs to link against. The TL;DR there are multiple sources of information (beyond just `copts`) the command line for compiler/linker invocation will be assembled from.

This description would pertain to auto-resolved toolchain or custom toolchain defining these features / having them patched in with [Legacy features patching logic](https://bazel.build/docs/cc-toolchain-config-reference#legacy-features-patching-logic). A fully (from scratch) custom toolchain could handle constructing the command line and tool calling differently.

Beyond that, I don't really have much insight into `cc_foreign` rules and while I understand the reason for their existence, I generally try to avoid their use (but your mileage may vary by your dependencies and control you have over the tree)... What struck me a little odd on the surface of it, while you say it works, I would not expect `copts` and passing via `CXXFLAGS` &Co. Since `RPATH` is very much a link time configuration, I would actually expect `linkopts` and "foreign" passing it through `LDFLAGS` to make more sense?

Comment: I guess `foreign_cc` just puts everything inside `copts` in all those compiler/linker-flags since that seems a normal thing to do. However I'm not so much interested in why or what exactly Bazel/foreign_cc are doing, but _how_ this Bazel-based workflow manages to suffix RPATH rather than just setting it - I'm not aware of any linker-flag providing this 'feature' and the generated `build_script.sh` I'm looking at does not manually concatenate any values as far as I can see..

Comment: @frans I've tried to beef up the answer a bit. Hope that helps to clarify the matter? Essentially, there are more things at play than just `copts`. If you for instance configured your cc toolchain to have nop `runtime_library_search_directories`.. it would not be adding the "other" `-rpath` flags... but would also break things for you unless `SOME_VALUE` is (always) reachable and populated.